# When creating an AMI from an instance store EC2, why do I need to use the -e exclude? Shouldn't --nofilter be used to keep the credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Following the steps in the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html:

> Prepare the bundle to upload to Amazon S3 using the ec2-bundle-vol
>   command. Be sure to specify the -e option to exclude the directory
>   where your credentials are stored.

For my instance my credentials are stored:

- In environment variables. And also in bashrc so each terminal has access to them
- In an ini file of my webservers home directory var/www, as per the PHP AWS SDK

If the purpose of is to create an AMI that can be stored in S3 and used to spin up new instances with, don't I want these credentials present on the AMI? Otherwise before I launch each EC2 with this new custom AMI I have to add the credentials to it each time?

Similarly, by default the

> By default, the bundle process excludes files that might contain
>   sensitive information. These files include *.sw, *.swo, *.swp, *.pem,
>   *.priv, *id_rsa*, *id_dsa* *.gpg, *.jks, */.ssh/authorized_keys, and */.bash_history. To include all of these files, use the --no-filter option. To include some of these files, use the --include option.

Again, wouldn't I want to include all of these things?

I am the only one on the AWS account though I have set up an IAM user which I use. Uploading this AMI to S3 with no exclude option and using --no-filter should be fine shouldn't it? It's not like anyone else can access it? So I'm confused why the documentation is advising this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the person launching an instance from an AMI would provide their own keypair and their preferred IAM role, both at launch time, so an AMI would typically contain *no* credentials.

Also, baking credentials into an AMI is a poor security practice in general, and is largely incompatible with the temporary nature of credentials.

[Updated answer ...]

Ideally, don't store *any* credentials in the AMI. After you launch an instance from an AMI:

- Your SSH public key gets pushed to the instance at launch time.
- The AWS credentials (access key, secret key, session token) come from the
  metadata service on the instance itself (assuming you launched with
  an IAM role).
- Other application-specific credentials e.g. DB creds
  can be retrieved at launch time, for example [from a secure S3 bucket](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx610S2MLVZWEA/Using-IAM-roles-to-distribute-non-AWS-credentials-to-your-EC2-instances).

Going back to your PHP INI question: if you are talking about providing credentials to the AWS PHP SDK, then you should not have to do that explicitly. Launch the instance with an appropriate IAM role and the PHP SDK will auto-retrieve, and auto-rotate, temporary credentials from the metadata service.

Comment: By credentials do you mean the aws access key and secret? Or do you mean the credentials to actually ssh onto the ec2 instance? For the aws access key and secret and aws php sdk documentation itself says to store the key and secret on the ec2 instance in an "ini" file